# Jquery Settimeout of variable

Tags: jquery

This is my jquery code i want to run timer of 1 second, each one second the timber updates the inner text of the div to +1 that shows the time just like a clock but i want to expire the timber after 15 seconds i mean i won't update the timer any more after 15 seconds.

```
var count = 0;
var Update_Div = setInterval(function(){
    count++;
    $("div").text(count);
    },1000);

    setTimeout(Update_Div, 15000);
```

But after 15 seconds that still updates the time, Please help me how can i fix it.
Sorry for bad english. I hope you understand just by watching the code.

Comment: You are using an interval and a timeout. Surely you want just to use an interval and clear it using `clearInterval(refInterval);` once `count` equal 15

Comment: you don't need set timeout here , use setInterval and clearInterval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you aren't doing anything with your `setTimeout()`, except passing it an intervals ID.

Clear your interval when your timeout is up:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    clearInterval(Update_Div);
}, 15000);
```

---

Although this relies on our timers working in sync with each other which more often than not, will be milliseconds in difference.

What you should do instead is not use `setInterval` and create a recursive function that uses only `setTimeout()`:

```
function countTo(max, n){
    var n = n || 1;
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('div').text(n);
        if(n < max) countTo(max, n + 1);   
    }, 1000);
}

countTo(15);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkwkyz0d/2/)

Comment: @HuskerNtn Glad to have helped, but please see my update with an improved version.

Answer (score 2):

```
var count = 0;
var Update_Div = setInterval(function() {
    count++;
    console.log(count);
    if (count == 15){
        clearInterval(Update_Div);
}
}, 1000);
```

Comment: You have to move if statement inside the interval, otherwise it is not going to be working.

Comment: OOps, you're right. I just changed the answer. Thanks :)